# How to display different message using VisualState Triggers in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm doing an UWP project and I wan't to display different type of informations depending on how many Items I have selected in a listview.

I wan't to display a different message in my TextBlock in these cases :
- No item selected
- One item selected
- Number of items selected

I found in WPF that there is something called : `DataTrigger` used like this :

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyList.Count}" Value="0">
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

What is the equivalent syntaxe in UWP using  `<VisualState.StateTriggers>` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get to be able to use a `DataTrigger` in UWP is to use a `DataTriggerBehavior` with a `ChangePropertyAction`: https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior

You will need to install [this official NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).